# Check if user registration field is set to visible or hidden on the registration form

Tags: users

In the user registration form, I have set a certain field say surname as hidden i.e. I have unchecked the checkbox saying "Display on user registration form." as shown below:

[image]

Now I want to disable the server side validation for this field. When I print the `$form` array, the surname field is still displayed. However I am not able to find any such value in the `$form` array which checks if the value is unchecked or not. **Is there any way to figure out if the said field is not displayed on the registration form?** Hope I am clear enough.

Comment: Check the `#access` key on the element render array and it's children, that usually determines whether a field is going to be rendered or not

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of [`user_register_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_form/7.x), you will notice it uses the following code.

```
  foreach (field_info_instances('user', 'user') as $field_name => $instance) {
    if (empty($instance['settings']['user_register_form'])) {
      $form[$field_name]['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
```

If you are implementing `hook_form_alter()` (or other similar hooks), it's quite easier to look at the #access property. If you need that in other functions, you can use code similar to the following one.

```
  foreach (field_info_instances('user', 'user') as $field_name => $instance) {
    if (empty($instance['settings']['user_register_form'])) {
      // $field_name is not supposed to be added to the account registration form.
    }
  }
```

Clearly, checking for the #access property in a `hook_form_alter()` implementation is the safer method, since it consider the field can be made accessible from third-party modules (or third-party modules can hide a field that should be visible).
The other method is more for getting a specific field setting.